# simplify arctan(x) + arctan(1/x) in sage

Tags: trigonometry, sage

In Sagemath, at some point I end up with the following expression (with b > 0):
[image]

Which would be easy to simplify using the
`arctan(x) + arctan(1/x) = pi / 2` equality.

My problem is: how do I simplify using that inequality? I tried `simplify_trig()` and `simplify_full()` but none of them worked.

Should I use something like `assume( arctan(1/sqrt(b-1)) + arctan(sqrt(b-1))) == pi / 2)` ? That looks like a ugly hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
sage: expr.subs({arctan(1/sqrt(b - 1)): pi/2 - arctan(sqrt(b - 1))})
```

Comment: oh that works. Is it considered good practice to use `subs` to make simplifications like that?

Comment: Yes, `subs` can perform any desired substitution on symbolic expressions, which is useful when "automatic" simplifications do not help.